# Android support small and normal screens

Tags: android, resize, size, screen

My app supports only small and normal screens, all density. I need that app will be avaliable for all devices in Google Play. Devices with Large and XLarge screens must zoom my app.

I write in manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="360"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Will my app avaliable in Google Play for all devices with any screens? Or it will be avaliable only for smallScreens and normalScreens?

How do I need write supports-screens manifest attribute to make app avaliable for all devices?

Answer (score 0):

Just change

- `android:largeScreens="false"` to `true`, and
- `android:resizeable="false"` to `true`, and
- `android:xlargeScreens="false"`  to `true`